# Connecting two Meteor 1.3 applications using DDP

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, cross-domain, ddp

I have two apps: `site` and `admin`.  I need `admin` to subscribe to one one of `site`s publications with DDP.  I can't find any recent articles or questions about this and nothing works.  I've pretty much removed all protections against XSS with no success.  Here is my code:

in `site/server/startup.js`

```
BrowserPolicy.content.allowSameOriginForAll("*");
BrowserPolicy.content.allowDataUrlForAll("*");
BrowserPolicy.content.allowOriginForAll("*");
```

in `site/server/publications.js`

```
Meteor.publish('asdf', function(){
    var self = this;
    self.added( "asdf", 'asdfasdfasdflLO', {"TEST","DATA"} );
    self.added('gallery', new Mongo.ObjectID("572b9503d338f74c4700bbbb"), {
        "uuid" : "566caf28-da7b-45d7-ad4a-523aba983cb3",
        "name" : "TEST GALLERY",
        "description" : "THIS IS A TEST",
        "order" : 0,
        "id" : 1
    });
    console.log("SUBSCRIPTION READY");

    self.ready();
    self.onStop(function(){console.log("SUBSCRIPTION STOPPED");
    })
});
```

in `admin/server/startup.js`

```
BrowserPolicy.content.allowSameOriginForAll("*");
BrowserPolicy.content.allowDataUrlForAll("*");
BrowserPolicy.content.allowOriginForAll("*");
```

in `admin/lib/...../connections.js`

```
import { DDP } from 'meteor/ddp-client' // behaves identically with or without this line

 SiteConnection = DDP.connect(Meteor.settings.public.site.rootUrl);
```

in `admin/client/……./page.js`

```
Template.page.onCreated(function(){
    console.log("created");

    FromSite = new Meteor.Collection();

    SiteConnection.subscribe('asdf', function() {
        console.log('Data list starts here:');
        FromSite.find().forEach(function(data){console.log(data)});
        Galleries.find().forEach(function(data){console.log(data)});
    });
});
```

---

When the admin page is visited, `site` logs `SUBSCRIPTION READY` but never sends any data.

On the other hand, when `site` subscribes to `asdf` itself, my DDP logger produces the following browser console output:

[image]

with this in mind we know:

- the publication works
- we are connecting to the correct URL

Why isn't `admin` getting any data?  Thanks in advance

*** UPDATE ***

Headers from both `site` and `admin`:

```
$curl -I https://www.site-local.com/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Mon, 09 May 2016 20:17:18 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-content-type-options: nosniff
access-control-allow-origin: *
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
content-security-policy: default-src 'self' data: http://* https://*; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: http://* https://*; connect-src * 'self' data: http://* https://*; img-src data: 'self' http://* https://*; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: http://* https://*;
```

As one can [see](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives) here:
`connect-src * 'self'`, the app is open to connecting with any domain via websockets.  Hope this helps narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
FromSite = new Meteor.Collection();
```

This line doesn't define the collection or the connection that the collection relates to. Although it also looks like you have confused the situation a little bit. There is not cross site data transfer here.
This isn't even needed:

```
SiteConnection = DDP.connect(Meteor.settings.public.site.rootUrl);
```

The problem is that your meteor collection on the client side doesn't describe the collection it refers to - what you need is this:

```
Template.page.onCreated(function(){
    console.log("created");

    FromSite = new Meteor.Collection('asdf');

    Meteor.subscribe('asdf', function() {
        console.log('Data list starts here:');
        FromSite.find().forEach(function(data){console.log(data)});
        Galleries.find().forEach(function(data){console.log(data)});
    });
});
```

Notice the changes on line 4 and 6

If I am not mistaken SiteConnection appears to just make a second connection to the default Meteor server.